# ETL pipeline from SQL Server to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, apache-spark, aws-lambda, pipeline

I need your comments about how to make a pipeline of data from SQL Server to MongoDB Atlas cloud. In this pipeline, I do many complicated tasks of transforming and even analysing and fault detection which needs comparison between current data and previously processed data.  There are some criteria of error which can only be calculated when the new data is compared with previously processed ones.
So, the pipeline is not just a single direction one. Can it be done with Kinesis- Lambda pipeline on AWS or it is better to be done with Kafka and Spark on our company's server and then upload the result to the cloud? In both cases, how my transformation unit can read the data from the destination.

I have depicted my two ideas in the image bellow.
[image]

Comment: `Kafka` and `Kinesis` both can handle high throughput data streaming. But do you need that here, as yours is ETL scenario?

Comment: You have not mentioned any performance requirements.  With these type of architectural questions I always ask myself "what would be easier for a new hire to understand and support if I were to leave the company".

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Kafka and Kinesis will just do the data streaming and decoupling. My main transformation function takes place in Lambda or Spark. I wish to know which track makes more sense.

Comment: @barrypicker Thank you for your comment. For me the learning curve of the next person is not currently a concern. Among my concerns is if the upper path even possible?? For example Lambda should be triggered by something like new data in Kinesis; then can I read data **simultaneously** from source (Kinesis) and destination (MongoDB) to do my comparison and analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use spark for all. Read from sqlserver, do your transformations and write out to mongo (sql server --> spark --> mongoDB):

```
#SQL server    
df = (
        spark
            .read
            .format('jdbc')
            .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
            .option('url', 'jdbc url')
            .option('user', user)
            .option('password', password)
            .option('dbtable', 'schema.table')
            .option('tempdir', 's3://....')
            .option('forward_spark_s3_credentials', 'true')
            .load()
    
        )
    
    # Mongo
df = spark.read.format("mongo").option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/people.contacts").load()
df.write.format("mongo").option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/people.contacts").mode("append").save()
```